# Why am I getting a description less regex_error?

Tags: c++, regex

I am trying to parse a file of locations with the following code however I am getting an odd regex_error and when I call the .what() function it simple gives "regex_error" with code 5, I can't seem to find the problem.

Code:

```
std::string line;
std::ifstream loc_file(argv[1]);
std::regex line_regex(R"(\S+)\s+([0-9\.]+) ([NS])\s+([0-9\.]+) ([EW])");
while (std::getline(loc_file, line)) {
    std::smatch m;
    std::regex_search(line, m, line_regex);
    std::cout << "Location Matches:" << m.length() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Loc:" << m[1];
    std::cout << " Lat:" << (m[3] == "S") ? -std::stod(m[2]) : std::stod(m[2]);
    std::cout << " Lon:" << (m[5] == "W") ? -std::stod(m[4]) : std::stod(m[4]) << endl;
}
```

File Format:

```
Loc1           0.67408 N   23.47297 E
Loc2           3.01239 S   23.42157 W
OtherPlace           3.64530 S   17.47136 W
SecondPlace          26.13222 N    3.63386 E
```

I developed my regex on regex101.com you can [test out my regex there](https://regex101.com/r/Xnpjxz/1)

Also if it matters I am using VS2015

Comment: Your raw string literal needs parentheses: `R"(<string in here>)"`

Comment: @Galik that worked, but why is it necessary? where can I find the docs on that?

Comment: [string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) #(6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out it has to do with the fact that I am using an unescaped String Literal, which requires parentheses. The fixed code is here:

```
std::string line;
std::ifstream loc_file(argv[1]);
std::regex line_regex(R"((\S+)\s+([0-9\.]+) ([NS])\s+([0-9\.]+) ([EW]))");
while (std::getline(loc_file, line)) {
    std::smatch m;
    std::regex_search(line, m, line_regex);
    std::cout << "Location Matches:" << m.length() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Loc:" << m[1];
    std::cout << " Lat:" << (m[3] == "S") ? -std::stod(m[2]) : std::stod(m[2]);
    std::cout << " Lon:" << (m[5] == "W") ? -std::stod(m[4]) : std::stod(m[4]) << endl;
}
```